# Substitution tag only outputting first word

Tags: html, perl, mason

I have the following perl mason code:

```
% my $var = "San Diego";
<input type="text" value=<% $var %> disabled />
```

However, when I do this, the value of the textfield only gets set to the first word. So in this case, it gets set to "San".  How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to enclose the value between double quotes

```
<input type="text" value="<% $concertCity %>" disabled />
```

Comment: *and* escape it properly for use in HTML: `value="<% $concertCity | h %>"`